# Write to csv with each item in a separate colum

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Currently I have a code that writes a bunch of key value pairs to a csv.  However, it's putting it all in the same column.  I want to separate the values from the keys to make it more readable.  This is going to be a lot of information so I want to make it as readable as possible.  Here is my code:

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import datetime
import re
import csv




#Gets the current time and returns it in ddmmyyyy format to match Transaction log file names

def timeteller():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    month = str('{:02d}'.format(now.month))
    day1 = now.day 
    day =  str('{:02d}'.format(day1))
    year =str(now.year)
    time =year+month+day
    return time

#Folder location for G4S unit transaction reports

def these_files(x, y):
    thislist = []
    configfiles = Path('O:/Unit Management/Reports/G4S/').glob('{}*/{}*Transaction.txt'.format(x, y))

    for files in configfiles:
        thislist.append(files)

    return thislist

#Checks to make sure the date and ba numbers are numbers only

def hasNumbers(inputString):
    numberfinal = []
    numberfinal = re.findall("[.0-9]", inputString)
    if numberfinal == []:
        numberfinal = '1'
    return numberfinal

#Selects which transaction reports to get the data from.  
#Transaction logs that have no date return nothing

def get_odometers(thesepath):
    get_this = []

    for thispath in thesepath:

        with open(thispath,"r") as f:
            searchlines = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
            if "StartDay" in line:
                get_this.append(line)



    return get_this

##Gets odometer numbers based on string match.  Puts each number in key value pair
#Serial Number added to key value pair

def make_pretty(checkthis):
    the_numbers = {}
    #the_numbers[''] = banumber
    for i, line in enumerate(checkthis):
        #the_numbers['Serial'] = banumber
        if 'StartDay' in line:
            for l in checkthis[i:i+1]: 
                numbers = l[59:67]
                #numberschecked = hasNumbers(numbers)
                the_numbers[banumber] = numbers



    return the_numbers

#Gets the time in integer format
intnow = int(timeteller())
#Goes back as many days as you would like, comment out to get yesterday
#intnow -= 1
#turns back to string
now = str(intnow)
thelist = []
#opens the banumbers list
thispath = open('banumberlist4.txt')
finallist = []
#counter to see what number it's on
counter = 0
#loop to iterate through each ba number
for files in thispath:
    getem = files
    banumber = getem[0:8]
    print(banumber)
    #combines each ba number with the date and time to match transaction report format
    combined = '{}_{}'.format(banumber,now)
    thepaths = these_files(banumber, combined)
    needtomakepretty = get_odometers(thepaths)
    goeslast = make_pretty(needtomakepretty)
    finallist.append(goeslast)
    counter+=1
    print(counter)

#writes to txt file in dictionary(key value pair (json)) format
f = open ('c:\\users\\me\\desktop\\versionstest.csv', 'w')
for ba in finallist:
    sba = str(ba)
    f.write('{}\n'.format(ba))
    #f.write(',')
```

At the end it comes out like this:

```
{'02105': '  (5.10)'}
```

Basically I want to separate the 02105 number from the 5.10 and have those in a separate column.  Any advice?

Comment: You are creating a "Comma Separated Values" file. You need to separate the values with commas.

Comment: Why are you writing *by hand* a json string instead of using the `json` or `csv` module? And why are you writing in json format when the file extension is `.csv`? What do you want to get in the end?

Comment: Cherry picked an old script of mine, thats why lol.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csv usually use some delimeters: ',' (comma), ' '(space), '\t'(tab), etc.

So you have to use ',' as delimeter rather than '_' on

```
combined = '{}_{}'.format(banumber,now)
```